# Dynamically change selected state of dropdown(s) for each row of data

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'd like to show dropdown menu(s) that contain the selected day based on what is recorded on the database.

Is there any efficient way to dynamically change the selected state of the dropdown menu based on the recorded data?

Thank you

note:

- There will be many dropdown menu(s) if the recorded day of the following clinicID is more than one row
- The $day is an integer, 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday and so on

Here is mycode

```
    // Check if any row existed
    if ($count>0) {
        // If row existed then start printing it
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
        {
            $day = $row['day'];
            $startHour = $row['startHour'];
            $startMin = $row['startMin'];
            $endHour = $row['endHour'];
            $endMin = $row['endMin'];

            echo 
            "<span>" .
            "<select name='day[]'>" .
            "<option value='1' selected='selected'>Sunday</option>" . 
            "<option value='2'>Monday</option>" . 
            "<option value='3'>Tuesday</option>" .
            "<option value='4'>Wednesday</option>" .
            "<option value='5'>Thursday</option>" .
            "<option value='6'>Friday</option>" .
            "<option value='7'>Saturday</option>" .
            "<option value='0'>Everyday</option>" .
            "</select>"

            //Please ignore this below
            "<br>start : " . $startHour . "." . $startMin . 
            "<br>end : " . $endHour . "." . $endMin . 
            "<br><br>";
        } 
    }
    else {
    }
```

Comment: Hi. If this is new code,  please use PDO or MySQLi. mysql is depreciated and should not be used on new code

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Try this link, it helped me a lot: phpdelusions.net/pdo by @Your-Common-Sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is new code, please use PDO or MySQLi. mysql is depreciated and should not be used on new code php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php Try this link, it helped me a lot: phpdelusions.net/pdo

Change your code to something like this (This code includes PDO implementation):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=yourhost;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'")); 

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



//Printing schedule already in the database
$getbusinesshours = "select * from businesshours where clinicID = $clinicID";

$stmt = $db->prepare($getbusinesshours);
$stmt->execute();

$count = $stmt->rowCount();

// Check if any row existed
if ($count>0){
    // If row existed then start printing it
    foreach ($stmt as $row){
    {
        $day = $row['day'];
        $startHour = $row['startHour'];
        $startMin = $row['startMin'];
        $endHour = $row['endHour'];
        $endMin = $row['endMin'];

        $i      = 0;

        $days   =   array('Everyday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
        $select = '<span><select name="day[]">';


        while($i <= 7){
            if($i == $day){
                $selected   =   'selected="selected"';
            }
            else{
                $selected   =   '';
            }

            $select =   $select.
            '<option value="'.$i.'"'.$selected.'>'.$days[$i].'</option'>

            $i++;
        }

        $select =   $select.'</select>';
        echo $select;

        //Please ignore this below
        "<br>start : " . $startHour . "." . $startMin . 
        "<br>end : " . $endHour . "." . $endMin . 
        "<br><br>";
    } 
}
else {
}

?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!